# Jenkins: How to execute powershell script after successful build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, post-build-event, post-build

I want to execute a powershell script (PS) upon **successful build** in Jenkins. This PS script basically deploys the application to web server. I see there are two plugins available [Hudson Post Build Task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) and [PostBuildScript Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) to run post deployment scripts.

Can I use any one of these two? Any recommendation of one over other?

Also both plugins has a *shell script* option. Is that powershell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there's also a third... the one I've used and the best suited for your situation is probably the [PowerShell Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin)

Comment: ye i finally ended up using PowerShell Plugin. With "Hudson Post Build Task" & "PostbuildScript Plugin" i could not execute powershell scripts. The only issue with Powershell plugin is that, it doesnt appear under "post build " section. Instead it appears under "Builds" section

Comment: But not having it be a 'post build' option might be a minor matter, depending on how your build is structured.  I get that you want to deploy the ear/war on successful builds, but if your post build steps are only let's say, compiling artifacts, etc.  It might be OK to deploy the ear/war if the artifact gathering fails.  However if you are doing more intensive things in post build, yeah... I can see where this is an issue.

Comment: i use MSbuild to build the .net application. The build scripts ie. .proj file builds the application and drops the packaged output in some directory. AFTER THE BUILD is done i am running powershell script to extract & deploy package to web servers. and this step i wanted to do it in postbuild..

Comment: Another option (and I know this is not ideal), is to have an entirely separate job fired off by say, the 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin' (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) at the conclusion of your existing job, which only step is to deploy the ear/war via PS

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is **no way of executing a Powershell script in the post-build section of a Jenkins job (yet).**

The search for the "[Recommended way to deploy a war-file to a Tomcat using Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572808/)" is based on that observation, that Powershell scripts need to be included in the build section for Jenkins Version 2.32.3.